# Getting Incorrect use of ParentDataWidget error when I use ListView

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-listview

In this part of my application I have `ListView`, when I run app I get this error and I can't resolve that:

```
Scaffold(
  body: Directionality(
textDirection: TextDirection.rtl,
child: Container(
  child: StreamBuilder(
    stream: globals.database.ticketsDao.getTicketsStream(),
    builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<List<Tickets>> snapshot) {
      if (snapshot.hasData) {
        return Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Expanded(
              child: ListView.separated(
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                    return ListTile(
                      title: Flexible(
                        child: Text(
                          snapshot.data[index].subject,
                          style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.caption.copyWith(fontFamily: 'IranSansBold'),
                        ),
                      ),
                      subtitle: Text(
                        snapshot.data[index].description,
                        style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.caption.copyWith(fontFamily: 'IranSansLight'),
                      ),
                    );
                  },
                  separatorBuilder: (context, index) {
                    return Divider();
                  },
                  itemCount:  snapshot.data.length),
            ),
          ],
        );
      } else {
        return Container(
            child: Center(
          child: Text(
            Strings.notAnyTickets,),
          ),
        ));
      }
    },
  ),
),
));
```

error:

```
══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY WIDGETS LIBRARY ╞═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════  
The following assertion was thrown building DefaultTextStyle(debugLabel:
((englishLike subhead  2014).merge(blackMountainView

subhead)).copyWith, inherit: false, color: Color(0xdd000000), family:
Roboto, size: 16.0, weight: 400, baseline: alphabetic, decoration:
TextDecoration.none, softWrap:  wrapping at box width, overflow:
clip):  Incorrect use of ParentDataWidget.

Flexible widgets must be
placed directly inside Flex widgets.  Flexible(no depth, flex: 1,
dirty) has a Flex ancestor, but there are other widgets between them:
 - _ListTile

 - Padding(padding: EdgeInsets(16.0, 0.0, 16.0, 0.0))
 - Semantics(container: false, properties: SemanticsProperties, selected: false, label: null, value:  null, hint: null, hintOverrides:
null)

 - Listener(listeners: [down], behavior: opaque)
 - _GestureSemantics
 - Listener(listeners: <none behavior: translucent)
 - RepaintBoundary
 - IndexedSemantics(index: 0)
 - KeepAlive(keepAlive: false)
 - SliverList(delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate#6802e(estimated child count: 19))

 - SliverPadding(padding: EdgeInsets(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 50.0))
 - Viewport(axisDirection: down, anchor: 0.0, offset: ScrollPositionWithSingleContext#c95ba(offset:
 0.0, range: null..null, viewport: 335.0, ScrollableState, AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics - ClampingScrollPhysics,
IdleScrollActivity#05a39, ScrollDirection.idle))
 - IgnorePointer-[GlobalKey#a3d1a](ignoring: false, ignoringSemantics: false)

 - Semantics(container: false, properties: SemanticsProperties, label: null, value: null, hint: null,  hintOverrides: null)
 - Listener(listeners: [down], behavior: opaque)
 - _GestureSemantics

 - Listener(listeners: [signal], behavior: deferToChild)
 - _ScrollSemantics-[GlobalKey#7cd1b]
 - RepaintBoundary
 - CustomPaint
 - RepaintBoundary
 - Expanded(flex: 1)  These widgets cannot come between a Flexible and its Flex.  The ownership chain for the parent of the offending
Flexible was:    DefaultTextStyle ← AnimatedDefaultTextStyle ←
_ListTile ← MediaQuery ← Padding ← SafeArea ←  Semantics ← Listener ← _GestureSemantics ← RawGestureDetector ← ⋯
```

Answer (score 5):

Flexible Widgets must be the direct child of an Expanded or Flex Widget.

In your case, you are using Flexible as a part of a ListTile widget, which is not a suitable parent.

> Flexible widgets must be placed directly inside Flex widgets.
>
> Flexible has a Flex ancestor, but there are other widgets between them: - _ListTile

Answer (score 0):

`Flexible` and `Expanded` can have `row`, `column` or `flex` as child, but not `ListView` related widgets.

If you still want the same feel of expanded properties in your widgets, use `ConstrainedBox`

Ex:

```
ConstrainedBox(
  constraints: BoxConstraints(minHeight: 50, maxHeight: 500),
  child: ListView.separated(...),
)
```

Answer (score 0):

For me the issue was using Expanded as a parent widget. I have unknowingly added an Expanded as:

```
 child: Expanded(
              child: Row(
                children: [
                  const SizedBox(
                    width: 15,
                  ),
                  Expanded().....
                  ])
                )
```

Then I removed the first Expanded

```
 child:  Row(
                children: [
                  const SizedBox(
                    width: 15,
                  ),
                  Expanded().....
                  ]
                )

and prob solved!!!
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 Widget                      Parent Widget
Expanded()               Row(), Column(), Flex()
Flexible()               Row(), Column(), Flex()
Positioned()                    Stack()
TableCell()                     Table()
```

Comment: You should add explanation.